# What's wrong with "i"? Asp.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am reading an MVC book and following the examples from it to create a music store project.

In one of the example, it creates a controller, calls an action method with a parameter in the URL. I found something interesting. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
    //
    // GET: /Store/

    public string Index()
    {
        return "Hello from Store.Index()";
    }

    // GET: /Store/Browse?genre=?Disco
    public string Browse(string genre)
    {
        string message =
        HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Store.Browse, Genre = " + genre);
        return message;
    }
    //
    // GET: /Store/Details/5
    public string Details(int id)
    {
        string s = "Store.Details, ID = " + id;

        return s;
    }

    }
}
```

In the last method "Details(int id)", if I call it using a URL like

```
http://localhost:4961/store/details/6
```

It's alright. But if I change the name of the parameter from "id" to "i", the compiler doesn't complain but when I ran it I would get an error message that I am unable to interpret.
Part of the error message is like this:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'i' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Details(Int32)' in 'MvcMusicStore.Controllers.StoreController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

So what is wrong if I just use "i" for integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because in your route definition you used {id}. Because Int32 is a value type it means that you have to pass a value for this parameter when invoking the action.

For example you could call it like this and still keep your default route definition with {id}

```
http://localhost:4961/store/details?i=6
```

Comment: You beat me to this response

Comment: Corect me if I'm wrong, but I thought the `{id}` in the routing is meant as a keyword and only indicates the value that takes that spot in the route will be an ID and thus a parameter. The fact that `id` works but not `i` is because the action method defined the parameter as `id`. They coincidentally have the same name and relate to eachother, but that's it.

Comment: Yes, that's true but also Int32 is a value type, it's why it doesn't work. Define i as string and it won't throw an exception, it will be null.

Comment: If the action signature were `string Details(int? i)` it would work without modifying the RouteConfig.

Answer (score 0):

You literally have to use the name of the variable (seriously).  I ran into this a while back and was.... let's say, surprised. The entry in the url must match the method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you change

```
public string Details(int id)
```

to

```
public string Details(int i)
```

then you introduce a breaking change. The code which called `Details` by passing parameter `id` is now passing a parameter which does not match. As a result, `Details` is called and `i` does not match anything. When calling and omitting a parameter, the parameter must be marked as optional with this syntax:

```
public string Details(int i = 0)
```

But since it is not, you get the error. Either change it back to `id`, or change the caller to use `i` (as @Darin points out, the binding is coming from your default route definition).

```
"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
```

You would need to change these to be

```
"{controller}/{action}/{i}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", i = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
```